# spring нужно сохранить объект, вместе с коллекцией других объектов внутри

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

у меня есть класс **Patent**

```
public class Patent {

private Integer id;
private Set<Participant> participants = new HashSet<Participant>();
private Date date;
private String patentAgency;
private String patentOwner;
private String regNumber;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Patent)) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.id == ((Patent) o).getId();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
}

public Patent() {
}//...constructosr, getter,setters, tostring}
```

Есть класс участников патента:

```
public class Participant implements Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private String patronymic;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Participant)) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.id == ((Participant) o).getId();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new Integer(id).hashCode();
}

public Participant() {
}//...constructosr, getter,setters, tostring}
```

Я пытаюсь, на одной странице создать патент и причислить к нему участников вытащенных из бд.
Страница `jsp`

```html
<body>
        <h1>Add patent</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <spring:url value="add_patent" var="formURL"/>
                <form:errors path="patent" cssClass="error"/>
                <form:form action="${formURL}"
                           method="post" cssClass="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"
                           modelAttribute="patent"
                           >
                           <!--...-->
                           <!--формы ввода полей патента-->
                           <!--...-->
                           <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Patronymic</th>
                            </tr>
                            <c:forEach items="${participants_to_add}" var="participant">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><form:checkbox path="participants" value="${participant}" label="${participant.id}" /></td>
                                    <td>${participant.firstName}</td>
                                    <td>${participant.lastName}</td>
                                    <td>${participant.patronymic}</td>              
                                </tr>            
                            </c:forEach>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create patent</button>
                </form:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Методы контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add_patent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addPatent(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("patent", new Patent());
    model.addAttribute("participants_to_add", dbService.findParticipants();
    return "add_patent";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add_patent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String savePatent(/*@Valid*/@ModelAttribute("patent") Patent patent, Errors errors, Model model) {
    System.out.println("post");
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("Has errors");
        System.out.println(errors);
        model.addAttribute("patent", patent);
        model.addAttribute("participants_to_add", dbService.findParticipants());
        return "add_patent";
    } else {
        dbService.addEvent(patent);
        return "add_patent";
    }
}
```

И в `errors` мне пишет:

> Field error in object 'patent' on field 'participants': rejected value [Participant{id=num, lastName=data, firstName=data, patronymic=data}]; codes [typeMismatch.patent.participants,typeMismatch.participants,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [patent.participants,participants]; arguments []; default message [participants]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'participants'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [model.Participant] for property 'participants[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

То-есть пришёл лист объектов, чекнутые из них после сабмита ушли обратно, но уже как массив строк... когда нужна коллекция set, чего ещё я не сделал? Может, мне нужен `InitBiner` для этого, но как его написать я не представляю.

Answer (score 0):

нашёл способ на javatalks. зарегистрировать парсер в initBiner,
а в качестве валуева положить не весь объект, а только id'шники
http://javatalks.ru/topics/38429